# To Animate textview inside linearlayout inside Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Okay so here is the situation...

There is a Linearlayout inside a Collapsing Toolbar Layout.

This LinearLayout contains a textview Which I want to animate..

Im trying to figure out a way to animate it so that it animates from the top to bottom of the Linear layout as im scrolling down.

You may see two Textviews Down there.. that was my way of giving the illusion of the same effect. If the user is not keen..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:elevation="0dp">



        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="156dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="18dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="    Pick  A  Restaurant    from  the  following  "
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="18dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="       Pick A Restaurant    from the following  "
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="115dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar4"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <!--            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"-->
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Okay so here is a little gif to demonstrate my problem

[image]

Ideally I would want the text view to animate down as im scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

it's almost the same as the motion layout, you can accept this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples

Comment: I went through the post. but I cant seem to understand how to implement it to my current code.. Im very new to android..

Comment: You can study harder by watching various tutorials on YouTube, keep learning